# Substring content between quotation marks

Tags: regex, r, substring

In a DF I have column entries of different length as the following:

`tmp_ezg.\"dr_HE_10691\"` , `tmp_ezg.\"dr_MV_0110200016\"` , `tmp_ezg.\"dr_MV_0111290017\"` etc.

How can I best substring what's in between the quotation marks?

My idea:

```
substring(DF$name, 10)
```

Since the content of the quotation marks has different lengths I cannot provide substring() a value where to stop.

Is there a possibility to substring only between certain symbols (i.e. quotation marks)?

Comment: This problem is tricky to handle using regex, because you may not know how many quote pairs you need to capture.  This is really a job for a parser to handle.

Comment: Can there be escaped quotes inside the quoted substrings? Are there only one quoted substring per string?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew: No there won't be escaped quotes inside the quoted substring and yes there's surely only one per string.

Comment: TimBiegeleisen: The answer of @lukeA works. It's hard to understand the regex expression though.

Comment: what's the down vote for? Too much of a beginner's question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
x <- c('tmp_ezg.\"dr_HE_10691\"' , 
       'tmp_ezg.\"dr_MV_0110200016\"' , 
       'tmp_ezg.\"dr_MV_0111290017\"')
res <- sub('.*?"([^"]+)"', "\\1", x)
print(res, quote=F)
# [1] dr_HE_10691     
# [2] dr_MV_0110200016
# [3] dr_MV_0111290017
```

... if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Can you explain that regex, please?

Comment: Sure. Match any characters until the first ", capture any non-" characters in \1 until a next ".

Comment: Thanks! The `?` is not necessary. What does `\\1` mean?

Comment: `\\1` is the first capture.

Answer (score 3):

To separate the content between the quotation marks (assuming there are exactly two in each entry), you just split the string by `\\\"` (escaped backslash and quotation mark):

```
y <- strsplit(x, split = "\\\"")
```

If all entries end with a quotation mark, this will give you a list of entries with two values, and the second value in each entry is your string.

```
[[1]]
[1] "tmp_ezg."         "dr_HE_10691"
[[2]]
[1] "tmp_ezg."         "dr_MV_0110200016"
[[3]]
[1] "tmp_ezg."         "dr_MV_0111290017"
```

Comment: Thanks for the strsplit() input. The answer of @lukeA works more nicely though